# State on a child element in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm new with react, and I wanted to know the best way of doing what I'm trying to do here. For simplicity sake, I'm making a page with 3 tabs that uses a child element as the tab content for each of the tabs. So my code looks like this:

```
var MainPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return { selectedTab: "one" };
  },
  selectTab(tabname) {
    let s = $.extend({}, this.state, { selectedTab: tabname })
    this.setState(s);
  },
  render() {
    let oneClassName, twoClassName, threeClassName = "";
    let tabContent;
    switch (this.state.selectedTab) {
      case "one":
        oneClassName = "selected";
        tabContent = <TabOne />;
        break;
      case "two":
        twoClassName = "selected";
        tabContent = <TabTwo />;
        break;
      case "three":
        threeClassName = "selected";
        tabContent = <TabThree />;
        break;
    }
    return (
      <div className="tabs">
        <span onClick={this.selectTab.bind(null, "one")} className={oneClassName}>ONE</span>
            <span onClick={this.selectTab.bind(null, "two")} className={twoClassName}>TWO</span>
            <span onClick={this.selectTab.bind(null, "three")} className={threeClassName}>THREE</span>
            <div className="tabcontent">
                {tabContent}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

Inside the different tabs (`<TabOne />`, `<TabTwo />`, `<TabThree />`) there are a seperate react class with it's own state, including some input elements. My problem is that when I switch from a tab, and then back again, the state of the tab get's reset. I would like it to keep the state when I switch back and forth between the different tabs. Anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical situation where you might want to consider giving your application more structure. There are several libraries out there that help you solve the problem of *Data Flow* within your application, for example [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux), [NuclearJS](https://github.com/optimizely/nuclear-js), [Alt](http://alt.js.org/) and many others. All these libraries implement some variant of the [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) architecture, but you're free to look for other solutions if you don't think Flux suits you (even though I recommend you look into it).

To solve the problem at hand without the need of a global state and application structure you could, however, decide to store all your data in you Main component and have the Tab components act as "dumb" components. In order to achieve this you should:

- Define a data structure within your `Main` component, in order for it to hold your data
- Have each `Tab` component fire an event whenever some of its content changes
- Have the `Main` component react to these events and use them to store the data coming from the Tabs into the data structure.

When inserting a tab you would have to do something like

```
<TabOne 
     onFormDataChange={(e, data) => { this.data.tabOne = $.extend({}, this.data.tabOne, data }} 
/>
```

and within the `Tab` you would need to call `props.onFormDataChange` when it's appropriate, passing to it whatever you need to.

This is, of course, just a general example, your mileage may vary. Take a look a some frameworks/libraries though, because your problem is something they can easily solve!

Comment: Redux looks promissing. That would certainly solve my issue, and give my application a much better structure. Thanks :)

Comment: I am partial towards Redux, as I'm using that in my projects and prefer it over the others. That said, everyone has its own style and personal preferences, so I suggest you try a couple before deciding which one is better for you. Glad to be of help ;)